# PostgreSQL result set length differ with joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, outer-join

The environment is: PostgreSQL 9.3

I have a request like:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT
  orders.id                      AS count,
  orders.state                   AS state,
  coalesce(discounts.amount, 0)  AS discount,
  CASE WHEN (order_logs.id IS NULL) THEN 0
  ELSE 1 END                     AS attempted,
  CASE WHEN (order_logs_1.id IS NULL) THEN 0
  ELSE 1 END                     AS processed,

-- the following 2-by-2 lines are comment-swapped
--   users.name                     AS "group",
--   order_logs_2.operator_id       AS group_raw
  goods.name                     AS "group",
  goods.id                       AS group_raw
FROM
  orders
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  order_logs
    ON
      order_logs.order_id = orders.id
      AND
      order_logs.state <= 1999
      AND
      order_logs.state != 1000
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  order_logs AS order_logs_1
    ON
      order_logs_1.order_id = orders.id
      AND
      order_logs_1.state <= 1999
      AND
      order_logs_1.state != 1000
      AND
      (order_logs_1.flags & 1) > 0
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  discounts
    ON
      discounts.user_id = orders.user_id
      AND
      discounts.goods_id = orders.goods_id

--the following 2 joins refer to the first commented-out lines in SELECT expression list
--   LEFT OUTER JOIN
--   order_logs AS order_logs_2
--     ON
--       order_logs_2.order_id = orders.id
--       AND
--       order_logs_2.state IN (
--         1999,
--         1100,
--         1150,
--         1151,
--         1003,
--         1202,
--         1203,
--         1200,
--         1201,
--         1002
--       )
--       AND
--       (order_logs_2.flags & 1 > 0)
--   LEFT OUTER JOIN
--   users
--     ON
--       users.id = order_logs_2.operator_id
  -- this join refers to the last 2 lines in expression list
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  goods
      ON
          goods.id = orders.goods_id
WHERE
  orders.ts_spawn >= 1414789200
  AND
  orders.ts_spawn < 1417381200
ORDER BY "count"
```

The problem is: when I use goods-based grouping the query returns like 20k rows of a result set (the same as `SELECT count(*) FROM orders WHERE ts_spawn >= 1414789200 AND ts_spawn < 1417381200`). But when I use operator_id-based grouping the result set contains much more (about +4k) rows. How is this possible? Why is result set growing when one changes joined tables/columns but not base table of a query?

Furthermore, I tried to eliminate usage of the table `users` with

```
order_logs_2.operator_id       AS "group",
order_logs_2.operator_id       AS group_raw
```

and then excluding corresponding JOIN-clause (the last of commented-out) with no luck.

Comment: Please post two _minimal_ queries that show the unexpected behaviour. You write about changing the grouping, and changing joined tables, but it is not clear what do you exactly change.

Comment: select * from A left outer join B on A.id=B.a_id; Will show those rows in A multiple times, that have multiple joineable rows in B. This way a left join increases the number of result rows.

Comment: The comments in SQL query show how it should be changed. The current form groups by goods. When I change grouping by operator_id I comment-out the last 2 lines in SELECT expression and comment-out the last LEFT OUTER JOIN, but uncomment those SELECT expression lines that are commented and uncomment those 2 LEFT OUTER JOINs that are commented. As for duplicate rows for the case there are multiple relations on 'JOIN ON' expressions: there's DISTINCT on the first selected column (which is the base query table's PK)

Comment: Also haven't simplified the query for 'minimal' because that's not so obvious that simplified form will show what's really my query do. Sometimes when one tries to obfuscate his code and then ask some help the only reaction is 'Show me the code!'.

Comment: DISTINCT as used in your example removes duplicate rows. If you want to use it on one column, you should write DISTINCT ON(orders.id)

Comment: Yep, my fault. Misunderstood DISTINCT usages. With DISTINCT ON() the query runs as it was planned. Thanks.